# Simple find/replace using regex in Eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse, replace

I have the following possible lines in my code

```
addEventListener(PropertyChangeEvent.PROPERTY_CHANGE, propertyChangeHandler)
addEventListener("click", propertyChangeHandler)
addEventListener(PropertyChangeEvent.PROPERTY_CHANGE, _propertyChangeHandler)
addEventListener(PROPERTY_CHANGE, _propertyChangeHandler)
```

They all have in common that they start with `addEventListener(` have one `,` in the middle and end with a `)`

What would be the proper regex to cover all cases and add `,false,0,true` before the closing parenthesis `)`

So it would look like:

```
addEventListener(PROPERTY_CHANGE, _propertyChangeHandler ,false,0,true )
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A matching regex would be: `(addEventListener\([^,]+,[^)]+)\)`. The corresponding replace expression is `$1,false,0,true)`.